# What is the right way to make a delete product button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want the #zakaz-pusto object to be displayed again after removing an item from the cart. And for me, everything is deleted, but the object is not visible. What's wrong with that?

For the most part, the shopping cart is working properly.

```
$(document).ready(function CartLogic() {
    const cart = [];

    const itemx7 = {
        name: 'item1',
        price: 10190,
        quantity: 1,
    };

    $('.button-buy').click(function BuyItem() {
        $('#zakaz-pusto').hide();
        $('#cart-object').show();

        const existingItem = cart.find(item => item.name === itemx7.name);

        if (existingItem) {
            existingItem.quantity++;
        } else {
            cart.push({...itemx7, quantity: 1});
        }

        updateCartDisplay();
    });

    function updateCartDisplay() {
        const cartContainer = $('#zakaz-menu');

        cartContainer.empty();

        cart.forEach(item => {
            const itemHTML = `<div class="cart-item">
                            <span class="item-name">${item.name}</span>
                            <button class="quantity-button increase" data-action="increase" data-name="${item.name}">+</button>
                            <span class="item-quantity">${item.quantity}</span>
                            <button class="quantity-button decrease" data-action="decrease" data-name="${item.name}">-</button>
                            <span class="item-price">${item.price * item.quantity} ₽</span>
                            <button class="quantity-button item-delete" data-action="item-delete" data-name="${item.name}">✕</button>
                          </div>`;
            cartContainer.append(itemHTML);
        });

        let totalAmount = 0;
        cart.forEach(item => {
            totalAmount += item.price * item.quantity;
        });

        const totalAmountContainer = $('#zakaz-summa');

        totalAmountContainer.empty();

        totalAmountContainer.text(`${totalAmount} ₽`);

        //////<---->//////
        if (cart.length === 0){
            cartContainer.append($('#zakaz-pusto'))
        }
        //////<---->//////
    }

    $('#zakaz-menu').on('click', '.quantity-button', function () {
        const action = $(this).data('action');
        const itemName = $(this).data('name');
        const itemToUpdate = cart.find(item => item.name === itemName);

        if (action === 'increase') {
            itemToUpdate.quantity++;
        } else if (action === 'decrease' && itemToUpdate.quantity > 1) {
            itemToUpdate.quantity--;
            //////<---->//////
        } else if (action === 'item-delete') {
            cart.length = 0;
        } else if (action === 'decrease' && itemToUpdate.quantity === 1){
            cart.length = 0
        }
            //////<---->//////
        updateCartDisplay();

    });
});
```

Comment: Your issue is that you put the -pusto inside -menu but then you delete everything in -menu.    `cartContainer.append($('#zakaz-pusto'))` **moves** `-pusto` it doesn't add a copy - try ``cartContainer.append($('#zakaz-pusto').html())` or `.clone()`

Comment: Change `cartContainer.append($('#zakaz-pusto'))` to `$('#zakaz-pusto').show()`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I'm not good at English.
I was able to solve this problem.
Made just 2 entities, one hides when the cart is not empty, the second appears after deleting items, and the first is hidden.

Comment: Please see [answer]. Solutions should be more specific and include code. Also take the [tour].